# jquery/css to access the following anchor tag in the below HTML

Tags: jquery, css, sharepoint

I have the following generated html i would like to apply css for the element 
"STPrograms"

i tried with following css but it is applied to all li elements in the div with id DeltaTopNavigation

```css
#DeltaTopNavigation ul li a:first-child span span {
    color: #F7901E !important;
    font-size:large;
}
```

```html
<div id="DeltaTopNavigation" class="ms-displayInline ms-core-navigation" role="navigation">
  <div id="zz12_TopNavigationMenu" class=" noindex ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox">
  <ul id="zz13_RootAspMenu" class="root ms-core-listMenu-root static">
   <li class="static selected">
    <a class="static selected menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-core-listMenu-selected ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" href="/sites/STPrograms/SitePages/Home.aspx" accesskey="1">
     <span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">STPrograms</span>
      <span class="ms-hidden">Currently selected</span>
     </span>
    </a>
    <ul class="static">
    <li class="static"><a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" href="/sites/STPrograms/CBP Master/Forms/AllItems.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Navigation1</span></span></a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="static ms-verticalAlignTop ms-listMenu-editLink ms-navedit-editArea"><span class="ms-navedit-editSpan" id="zz12_TopNavigationMenu_NavMenu_Edit"><a id="zz12_TopNavigationMenu_NavMenu_EditLinks" class="ms-navedit-editLinksText" href="#" onclick="g_QuickLaunchMenu = null; EnsureScriptParams('quicklaunch.js', 'QuickLaunchInitEditMode', 'zz12_TopNavigationMenu', 1, 1, 0, '\u002fSITES\u002fSTPROGRAMS'); cancelDefault(event); return false;"><span class="ms-displayInlineBlock"><span class="ms-navedit-editLinksIconWrapper ms-verticalAlignMiddle"><img class="ms-navedit-editLinksIcon" src="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=23"></span><span class="ms-metadata ms-verticalAlignMiddle">Edit Links</span></span></a><span id="zz12_TopNavigationMenu_NavMenu_Loading" class="ms-navedit-menuLoading ms-hide"><a id="zz12_TopNavigationMenu_NavMenu_GearsLink" href="#" onclick="HideGears(); return false;" title="This animation indicates the operation is in progress. Click to remove this animated image."><img id="zz12_TopNavigationMenu_NavMenu_GearsImage" src="/_layouts/15/images/loadingcirclests16.gif?rev=23"></a></span><div id="zz12_TopNavigationMenu_NavMenu_ErrorMsg" class="ms-navedit-errorMsg">
    </div></span>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's applied to all the links inside the element with ID `DeltaTopNavigation`, as expected. Perhaps you meant `#zz12_TopNavigationMenu`? Anyway please try to format the HTML markup a bit better so it's more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the immediate child selector >

**Example:**

```
#DeltaTopNavigation > ul > li > a > span > span {
    color: #F7901E !important;
    font-size:large;
}
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors

Comment: its not applying for any element now

Comment: thanks it worked need to add div after id                          #DeltaTopNavigation >div> ul > li > a > span > span {
    color: #F7901E !important;
    font-size:large;
}

Comment: Sorry, mislead by the indentation in the HTML, but you got the idea.  Glad to help.